# Is the phrase "was being" an excessive use of the verb "to be" and wrong?

Tags: verb-forms

Sentence in question:

> The Santa Catalina mountains were formed 12 million years ago during a period when the Western North American Continent ***was being*** stretched.

I think the sentence should be corrected as

> The Santa Catalina Mountains had been formed during a period 12 million years ago when the Western North American Continent ***was stretching***.

Is my correction correct or better?

Comment: What is with the close votes??

Answer (score 10):

No, the original is better. "Was being stretched" implies that something (plate tectonics) was stretching North America; "was stretching" implies that it was stretching itself.

Answer (score 4):

*Stretch* has three distinct senses.

- As an intransitive verb it may have either a *stative* sense, meaning “have physical extension”, or an *eventive* sense, meaning to “increase one’s own physical extension”.

> - INTR. STATIVE: The Northeast Megalopolis stretches from Boston in the north to Washington in the south.
> - INTR. EVENTIVE: John rose, stretched, and set about making breakfast.

- As a transitive verb it has the eventive sense “cause the physical extension of *[Direct Object]* to increase”.

  > - TR.: John stretched a sheet over the body.

*Stretch* is used transitively here, and *was being stetched* is a passive construction. That makes good sense: the continent is represented as being stretched by external geological forces as opposed to ‘stretching’ by its own efforts or volition.

*Was stretching* is an active construction, and in the absence of a Direct Object must have an intransitive sense. With an inanimate subject intransitive ‘stretch’ ordinarily has a the *stative* sense:

> The North American continent stretches from the Atlantic to the Pacific.

But a stative does not usually accommodate the progressive construction *was stretching*. Moreover, stative *stretch* requires that the extension be defined, usually with preposition phrases *from X to Y*; that is absent here.

That leaves *stretch* in an eventive sense. That sense is very unusual with an inanimate subject: we say that a person or cat ‘stretches’ (intransitive) upon waking up, but to say that a continent ‘was stretching’ falls very odd on the ear.

I think *Was being stretched*, meaning “was being caused to increase in physical extension”, is the only likely construction here.

Comment: what would "was stretching" mean?

Comment: @Ben It would have to be intransitive eventive, meaning "was increasing its own physical extension", as in "She was stretching to reach the top shelf."

Comment: does this apply to any other verb?

Comment: @Ben Good question. I can't think of one that follows this particular pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It's used colloquially often.

- "I should have given you the money back, I was being stupid."
- "She wasn't flirting with you, she was just being friendly."

In your case "was being" is correct. The meanings are different - "was being stretched [by something]" v. "was stretching [on its own]". In particular in the first case it's the *transitive* verb, and in the second case it's the *intransitive*.

In general, "was being" is a normal construct.